# Two files containing definition of main() Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have created a project in Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition.

This project contains one .cpp file for each assignment like this...

```
[-]Source Files
   \
   |-- 233.cpp
   |-- test.cpp
```

**And each file contains definition of main().**

Action:CTRL+F5

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: _main already defined in 233.obj test.obj
Error   2   fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

**How do I compile and see output of each file ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have 2 functions called main() in a single project. What you should do is change the names of the functions, and then call them from a new main() function which would function as a menu.

If you make them separate projects, you can switch which one to run with Solution Properties -> Startup Project.

Answer (score 3):

I guess in your situation your project consists of just one file. If you want to compile them separately then I suggest:

- create individual project (CSPROJ) file per each of them
- use command line compiler CSC to compile these files separately
- or (as suggested) rename your current Main methods to Run methods, create a separate file named Program.cs with just the Main method and from this method call to a particular Run method (depending on which task you want to execute)